# Probability problem from the "Undoing Project" by Michael Lewis

Tags: probability

Just finished reading "The Undoing Project" by Michel Lewis One of the examples cries for an online explanation of how the answers 75%, 90% and 33.3% (according to the author) were derived. Here is the problem from the book. Two bags have 100 chips. You know one bag has 75 red and 25 white; the other bag has 25 red and 75 white chips. You must select one of the bags and pull out chips. You pull a red chip. What are the odds that the you pulled from the bag having a majority of red chips ? (75%) If you pull another red chip. What are the odds that you have pulled from the bag that has the majority of red chips? (90%) What are the odds that you are still pulling from the bag with the majority of red chips if the third chip you pull is white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all conditional probabilities. Let's say $A$ is the event that you selected the first bag (with $75$ red chips and $25$ white chips), and use $R$ and $W$ to denote picking a red or white chip respectively (as part of a sequence). Then:

I. Here they ask for $P(A|R)$

II. Here they ask for $P(A|RR)$

III. Here they ask for $P(A|RRW)$

Do you know how to find such conditional probabilities?

OK, here goes:

First a little conceptual explanation. We know that $P(R|A)=0.75$, and someone might think that this is where the $0.75$ answer to question I comes from, but that's not what the question asks. The question asks for $P(A|R)$, which is different. Indeed, suppose the second bag (call it $B$) *also* had $75$ red chips and $25$ white chips ... then of course the fact that we picked a red chip would not provide any more evidence that we picked the chip from bag $A$ rather than bag $B$, and so we would then have $P(A|R)=0.5$.  In other words, it's really the fact that $A$ has (proportionally)  more red chips than bag $B$ that makes it more likely that you were picking from bag $A$ instead of bag $B$ given that you picked a red chip.

OK, so that's conceptually. How do we actually quantify this? Well, as a general principle let's note that:

$$P(R \cap A) = P(R | A) \cdot P(A)$$

(Makes sense: what's the probability of two events happening? It's the probability of one of them happening, times the probability of the second one happening, given that the first one happens)

But we also have:

$$P(A \cap R) = P(A | R) \cdot P(R)$$

But of course

$$P(R \cap A) = P(A \cap R)$$

And thus we have:

$$P(R | A) \cdot P(A)= P(A | R) \cdot P(R)$$

from which we can isolate $P(A|R)$:

$$P(A | R)= \frac{P(R | A) \cdot P(A)}{P(R)}$$

This last equation is known as Bayes' formula.  Personally, I don't remember Bayes' formula, but derive it from the much easier to remember step before it whenever I need it.

OK, but we know:

$$P(A)=0.5$$

$$P(R|A) = 0.75$$

and as far as $P(R)$ goes:

$$P(R)= P(R|A)\cdot P(A) + P(R|A^C)\cdot P(A^C) = 0.75\cdot0.5+0.25\cdot0.5 = 0.5$$

Thus, we get:

$$P(A | R)= \frac{P(R | A) \cdot P(A)}{P(R)}= \frac{0.75\cdot 0.5}{0.5}=0.75$$

II. OK, so now we want $P(A|RR)$

Well, we can do something similar:

$$P(A | RR)= \frac{P(RR | A) \cdot P(A)}{P(RR)}$$

We have:

$$P(RR|A)= \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{3}{4}=\frac{9}{16}$$

(I am assuming pulling with replacement .. though with these big numbers, without replacement you'd still get something close to this)

and:

$$P(RR|A^C)= \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{16}$$

$$P(RR)= P(RR|A)\cdot P(A) + P(RR|A^C)\cdot P(A^C) = \frac{9}{16}\cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{16}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{10}{32}$$

And so:

$$P(A | RR)= \frac{P(RR | A) \cdot P(A)}{P(RR)} = \frac{\frac{9}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{10}{32}}=\frac{\frac{9}{32} }{\frac{10}{32}}=\frac{9}{10}$$

Comment: No.  I would appreciate being led through the problem and its solution slowly and definitely think such an analysis would help readers of this popular book.

Comment: @sburech OK, I'll do the first two ... after that I think you'll get how to do the third one.

Comment: In the book, he says that pulling a white chip on the third try reduces the probability that you are pulling from the bag with the majority of red chips down to 33 ⅓ %.

Comment: @sburech Well, just intuitively, if you pick 3 chips and two are red and one is white (i.e. 2/3 are red), is it more likely you are dealing with the bag where 3/4 of the chips are red, or the bag where 1/4 of the chips are red? Just eyeballing that, I would say you are more likely to deal with the bag that has 3/4 red ... so that would suggest more than 50%, rather than 33.3% ... so this *seems* wrong to me ... but, *math* should give us the exact answer!

Comment: OK on the first draw.  Now please derive the second draw which is red (author says its 90% chance it came from the bag with the majority of red chips) and then the third draw which is white (and the author says that the probability that it came from the bag with the majority of red chips drops to 33 ⅓% and which you think may be wrong.)

Comment: @sburech Just added the second answer ... Can you do the third yourself now?  And no, I don't get 33.3% .. I wonder if I misinterpret the question ... something with the *still* pulling from the first bag maybe? Do you have the exact phrasing of that third question?

Comment: I am the one who misinterpreted; the author said the odds revert back to 3:1 when a while chip is selected on the third pull which is a 75% chance that it was selected from the bag with the majority of red chips.  Is this what you get?

Comment: It also is pulling without replacement.  Could you show me how that changes the calculations?

Comment: @sburech Ah!  And yes, that's exactly what I got! Did you try and find this yourself?  It's the same method ...

Comment: @sburech Ugh, without replacement?  Well, instead of the second chip being red with a probability of 3/4, it would then be 74/99 ... math gets nasty fast ... I'd say: close enough to 3/4 to keep working with that!

Comment: Yes and I think without replacement it still rounds to 75%.  Thanks so much for all your help.  One more non-mathematical question, though.  Where is the sign-out tab for the math.stackexchange, since I am a total newbie to this site.

Comment: @sburech Huh, I don;t know .. I guess I never sign out :)  But before you sign out: you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of it.

Comment: I did place a check mark and again appreciate your extreme patience and clarity of thought.  I guess I will just exit from the site.  I hope I am able to return when I feel perplexed again.

Comment: @sburech Glad I could help! :)